# How to dynamically add rows of views to a scrollview

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app where there is a ScrollView taking up part of a screen, but I need to dynamically add rows of views (a textView, 2 editText views, and a checkbox on each row, and then have more rows of those added dynamically) and be able to pull data from those to be put into a database.

I looked into doing a Grid View instead of a ScrollView, as well, and it seems like that might be a better way of doing this, but I'm not sure yet.

I'm pretty new to Android development, so I'm really not sure how to go about doing this, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds a lot like a ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you want to do a list of that "group" of items that change their content dinamically. For this purpose you can use a `ListView` and create a custom adapter class that extends `ArrayAdapter<?>`. You have also to create a custom XML layout for your adapter in which you put all those elements.

This link could help you: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html